# Replace the last character or number of a string | Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I need to check if the last number of character of a `${string}` is equal to `9`.
The string or numbers that I have to handle with is something `831`, `519` or `1351`.
However I dont know how do do it properly. I tried already something like:
`${string?replace((string.length)-1,"9")}`

At the end there should be instead of `831` --> `839` or `1351` --> `1359`  and so on.

Any sugestions about how I can archive this ?

Oh and by the way. If I use the fuction above this error massage comes up:
`Script error: You have used ?number on a string-value which is not a number (or is empty or contains spaces).`
And what I tried also was:
[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS9p9.png)
Because the original number is somethink like `831.896`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [string slicing](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_stringop_slice) to keep all characters except for the last one like this:

```
<#assign string = "1234">
<#assign string = string[0..<string?length-1] + "9">
${string}
```

Results in:

```
1239
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly fine for my case. But my code is as follows: `${string[0..string?length-6]+9}`. Is the < in your answer just a typo or intetional ? If it is intentional, what does it mean ?

Comment: No, it's not a typo. See https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_seqenceop_slice

Comment: Ah yes I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to replace that thing, use `?replace`. This replaces the last character with 9, if the last character is a digit that's not already 9:

```
${s?replace("[0-8]$", '9', 'r')}
```